# Moderator Notifications

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-page

We have a rather large site and we power the comments on it with Facebook.

We have both defined an appid and some additional moderators.

The problem is that these moderators get a Facebook notification (red blob) for every comment on the site. Which is pretty much all the time.

Is there any way so we can disable these notifications for them?

Answer (score 0):

The only option as far as I know is to change the Email notification settings and I believe that that hides and notifications within Facebook (I'm in China so I am unable to check this personaly).

Login as an admin/mod and click:
`Edit Page` --> `Your Settings` --> `View All Email Settings For Your Pages` --> `Change email notification settings for individual pages` --> Then uncheck `User comments`.